# Remote Powershell Connection to Exchange using a managed service account

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Is there a way to use a managed service account (msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount) to connect to Exchange via Powershell? Our scenario is as follows:
We have a service component written in c# that connects to Exchange via Remote Powershell. The service component runs as a managed service account.

The call to New-PSSession is as follows:

```
New-PSSession 
-Configurationname Microsoft.Exchange 
-ConnectionUri "http://server/powershell" 
-Authentication Kerberos 
-AllowRedirection 
-ErrorAction Stop
```

As you can see, a credential is not specified so the credential that is sent to the Exchange server is the credential of the current user (which seems to work when looking at the returned errormesage). 
The result is the following error:

```
Processing data from remote server  failed with the following error message:
[ClientAccessServer=...,BackEndServer=...,RequestId=...,TimeStamp=...] 
[AuthZRequestId=6c727005-565b-4019-855f-657ae6b86ee7][FailureCategory=AuthZ-CmdletAccessDeniedException] 
The operation couldn't be performed because 'domain\account$' couldn't be found.
```

*domain\account$* shows the correct login of the managed service account.

The eventlog of the exchangeserver also states:

```
Source: "MSExchange RBAC", Event ID: 16):
(Process w3wp.exe, PID 8980) 
"RBAC authorization returns Access Denied for user domain\account$ (SID=S-...). 
Reason: User was not found on Domain Controller XYZ.
```

I currently suspect, that the RBAC "component" explicitly looks for objects of type 'user' in Active Directory but not for msDS-GroupManagedServiceAccount objects so I wonder if this is supported at all.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We still user a "regular" user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and found a [statement by Microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94317044-4fe6-4fe9-867c-db36a0c380d7/can-a-gmsa-account-perform-exchange-operations-on-onprem-exchange-server?forum=Exch2016Adm):

"Group Managed Service Accounts (gMSA) are not supported in on-premises Exchange Server environments and thus cannot be used to perform Exchange things."

Answer (score 1):

No, a Managed Service Account is local to the host you define it on. Windows 2012 introduced [gMSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview) which can be used on multiple hosts. You may have better luck using one of them. Also, you have to grant the account the correct permissions/RBAC roles depending on the commandlets you need to run.

Comment: The service account is actually a group managed service account. In our test environment, the service compoment, Exchange and the gMSA are all on one host. The gMSA is member of an AD group, that is member of the appropriate RBAC roles. Adding the gMSA directly via Add-RoleGroupMember is not possible (object not found error).